# Pre-Signed S3 URL Signature Does Not Match

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Title says everything. Here is my code;

I'm using node-formidable for files.

```
form.on("end",function(field, file){
        params.Body = fs.createReadStream(params.filePath)
        delete params.filePath;
        S3.getSignedUrl('putObject',params, function(err, url) {
            if(err){console.log(err);}
            console.log(url);
        });
    })
```

After successful upload, url variable returns s3 url, something like this;

https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/746575308_8c081369df.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=[key]&Expires=[date]&Signature=[signature]&x-amz-acl=public-read

But still getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error. In description says

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Here is my parameters

```
params = {
    Bucket:"bucketname",
    Key: file.name,
    ACL: 'public-read'
}
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ran into the same problem while using `S3.getSignedUrl('putObject'`, serverside, and then trying to use that url clientside.

What I noticed in my case, which might be relevant to yours, is that signatures created with all the `S3.getSignedUrl` take into account request headers. So if you are generating a URL, it will fail with the same error message you received unless sent with the same headers.

One example of a failure: Generated like this..

```
var params = { Bucket: 'YourBucket', Key: 'uniqueFileKey', Expires: 10000 };
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if(err){
        return cb(err);
      }
      return cb(null, url)
    });
```

The following request fails when a using that same url generated. This request was made from a browser.

```
RequestMethod: Put
Headers: {
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:11768
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
}
```

And the difference is that the signature above created doesn't include content-type, where the request does specify a content-type. Params need to match headers, or the error thrown will be signature doesn't match.

Successful example below:

```
var params = { Bucket: 'YourBucket', Key: 'uniqueFileKey', Expires: 10000, ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' };
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if(err){
        return cb(err);
      }
      return cb(null, url)
    });
```

Comment: @farrellw : A small typo, the line of the successful example should be:
`var params = { Bucket: 'YourBucket', Key: 'uniqueFileKey', Expires: 10000, ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' };` (without `-`)

Comment: @SvenDukat Fixed

Comment: even if you have the content type correct, you will also get this error if you use a POST request from the browser instead of a PUT (as I have just found out after 2 hours of banging my head against a wall)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. The answer from farrellw explains the reason.

And in your case, you should add the header "**x-amz-acl**" with value "**public-read**" in your client request. Because you specified "ACL" with "public-read" when presigning on the server.

You can refer to https://aboutweb.dev/blog/signaturedoesnotmatch-s3-direct-upload/ for more details

Answer (score -5):

Give this a try. You need to upload the object, then generate the signed url against an existing object.

```
var s3bucket = 'somebucket';
var s3Key = '/some/key',
var body = fs.createReadStream('/some/local/file.txt');

var params = {
    Bucket: s3bucket,
    Key: s3Key,
    Body: body
};
s3.upload(params, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        cb_1(err);
    } else {
        var params = {
            Bucket: s3bucket,
            Key: s3Key,
            Expires: parseInt(ttl)
        };
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function(err, url) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```