# Unable to upload file to s3 from react app

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having an issue uploading a pdf to s3 bucket from my react app.
I get an error when i try to push the file but the error is not very clear.

this is how I am generating the presigned_url on my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import boto3
import datetime
def create_file_upload_url_controller():
    try:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        print('create_file_upload_url_controller()')
        user_id = str(request.user.id)

        file_name = f"{user_id}_{datetime.datetime.utcnow()}"
        bucket_name = "docwise-large-files-dev"
        print(f'file_name: {file_name}')

        # Generate pre-signed URL for upload
        presigned_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            'put_object',
            Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': file_name},
            ExpiresIn=3600,  # URL valid for 1 hour
            HttpMethod="PUT"
        )
        
        print(f'presigned_url:  {presigned_url}')

        return jsonify({'upload_url': presigned_url, 'file_name': file_name})

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'e: {e}')
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
```

this is the component that collects the file from the user::

```
// FileUpload.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addFile } from '../../../../../../actions/filesActions';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const FileUpload = ({ onFileChange, addFile, conversation_id,files }) => {
  const { chatId } = useParams();

  useEffect( ()=>{
  },[files])

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      const file = selectedFiles[i];
      const fileDetails = {
        conversation_id: chatId,
        file: file,
      };
      addFile(fileDetails);
    }
  };



  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file"  onChange={handleFileChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  files: state.files.files
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  addFile,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(FileUpload);
```

this is the action that pushes the file to aws s3::

```
// filesActions.js

export const ADD_PDF = 'ADD_PDF';
export const ADD_PDF_SUCCESS = 'ADD_PDF_SUCCESS';
export const ADD_PDF_FAIL = 'ADD_PDF_FAIL';
export const DELETE_PDF = 'DELETE_PDF';
export const UPDATE_PDF = 'UPDATE_PDF';

// /api/file/create_file_upload_url_url



let baseUrl;
if (process.env.MODE === 'local') {
  baseUrl = `/api/file/`;
} else {
  baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/file/`;
}


export const addFile = (pdfDetails) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const { token } = getState().auth;

    const createFileUploadURLResponse = await fetch(`${baseUrl}create_file_upload_url`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: null,
    });

    if (createFileUploadURLResponse.error != null) {
      console.log('error: ', createFileUploadURLResponse.error);
      return dispatch({
        type: ADD_PDF_FAIL,
        payload: createFileUploadURLResponse.error,
      });
    }

    const createFileUploadURLResponseData = await createFileUploadURLResponse.json();

    console.log(`createFileUploadURLResponseData:  ${createFileUploadURLResponseData.upload_url}`);
    console.log(`key : ${createFileUploadURLResponseData.file_name}`)

    console.log('pdfDetails.file:   ',pdfDetails.file);


    console.log('before uploading file to s3')

    const uploadFileResponse = await fetch(`${createFileUploadURLResponseData.upload_url}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': pdfDetails.file.type,  // Change to file's actual MIME type
        'Key': `${createFileUploadURLResponseData.file_name}`,
      },
      body: pdfDetails.file,
    });
    const uploadFileResponseData = await uploadFileResponse.json();

    console.log(`uploadFileResponseData:  ${JSON.stringify(uploadFileResponseData)}`);



  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
    return null;
  }
};
```

This is the error that I am getting::

```
filesActions.js:52     PUT https://docwise-large-files-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/Juan_Casas_Resume.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAYNCJFQSXTCQHFGR3&Signature=GTb89cRSPxDQhp0TmTfuggDKPfc%3D&Expires=1692137811 403 (Forbidden)
```

I found this article but It didnt help::
https://fullstackdojo.medium.com/s3-upload-with-presigned-url-react-and-nodejs-b77f348d54cc

[SignatureDoesNotMatch: rejecting SignedURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606141/signaturedoesnotmatch-rejecting-signedurl)

this is the network tab
[image: networktab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the headers on both server and front end need to be the same.

I needed these headers in the backend;:

```
            Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': file_name, 'ContentType': "application/pdf",},
```

i was missing the content-type