# How to set Content-Type header with boto3 presigned url multipart upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, http-headers, boto3, botocore

Is there any way to allow `Content-Type` header with multipart uploads to presigned s3 url?

Let's begin with the following code:

```py
import boto3
import requests


BUCKET_NAME = "foo"

# No, it's global in this MRE only
client = boto3.client('s3')


def create(key):
    response = client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=key)
    return response['UploadId']


def get_url(key, upload_id, chunk_number):
    signed_url = client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='upload_part',
        Params={
            "Bucket": BUCKET_NAME,
            "Key": key,
            "PartNumber": chunk_number,
            "UploadId": upload_id,
            # "ContentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        ExpiresIn=60 * 60,  # seconds
    )
    return signed_url


def complete(key, upload_id, parts):
    client.complete_multipart_upload(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Key=key,
        UploadId=upload_id,
        MultipartUpload={"Parts": parts}
    )


def test_upload():
    key = 'data/foo.bar'
    upload_id = create(key)

    url = get_url(key, upload_id, 1)
    with open("/tmp/foo.bar", "rb") as src:
        response = requests.put(url, data=src.read())

    etag = response.headers["ETag"]
    complete(key, upload_id, {"ETag": etag, "PartNumber": 1})
```

Hooray, this works. However, let's try to do the same from frontend, replacing `requests` call with

```
fetch(uploadTo, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: blob,
})
```

(no matter how blob is defined here, this is irrelevant to our problem).

And this fails, returning 403 `SignatureDoesNotMatch`. Why? Because `Content-Type` header *is* set (and `fetch` [cannot do without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670213/tell-fetch-to-not-send-a-content-type-header-at-all)), and this is part of S3-side backend signature verification. `Content-Type` is not a part of generated URL, so with any content type `fetch` tries to set this will not match. I know this is the case, because here's what response looks like (with only URL being different, ignore this incompatibilities, `uploadId=1` is just a fake - same thing happens with real URL; pay attention to **StringToSign** tag):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
    provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
  <AWSAccessKeyId>...</AWSAccessKeyId>
  <StringToSign>PUT
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    1684064749
    x-amz-security-token:FwoGZXIvYXdzEOT//////////wEaDE+2gqVw4NTt1c2eOCKGAVTf4uDCD+GJ8P6lG2vBg8yQ2dqyU7/6aHg4hXMljyDFByT7hJ1/F/GPwBi84eAMDZqGzXpIySe8PhU80ak5C4vg7vcGOOSaB3cXk7TtQ2q0pWb8MB0AYb3LGAJ6sahySjHSdArFFADB60u6SskWhq9HHSijilW9hKIiUgdceZAPhLH1J59oKITngqMGMijigFpTERPtZLB+MOjIqJIpHvPJrrfRg4mzwAmZbk+rropyYha4rBNP
    /sim-cal-bucket/temp/foo.mp4?partNumber=1&amp;uploadId=1</StringToSign>
  <SignatureProvided>miwrnxtxoPdGnuAEqiP52ZMscBQ=</SignatureProvided>
  <StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d
    77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 63 6f 64 65 64 0a 31 36 38 34 30
    36 34 37 34 39 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2d 74 6f 6b 65
    6e 3a 46 77 6f 47 5a 58 49 76 59 58 64 7a 45 4f 54 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f
    2f 2f 77 45 61 44 45 2b 32 67 71 56 77 34 4e 54 74 31 63 32 65 4f 43 4b 47
    41 56 54 66 34 75 44 43 44 2b 47 4a 38 50 36 6c 47 32 76 42 67 38 79 51 32
    64 71 79 55 37 2f 36 61 48 67 34 68 58 4d 6c 6a 79 44 46 42 79 54 37 68 4a
    31 2f 46 2f 47 50 77 42 69 38 34 65 41 4d 44 5a 71 47 7a 58 70 49 79 53 65
    38 50 68 55 38 30 61 6b 35 43 34 76 67 37 76 63 47 4f 4f 53 61 42 33 63 58
    6b 37 54 74 51 32 71 30 70 57 62 38 4d 42 30 41 59 62 33 4c 47 41 4a 36 73
    61 68 79 53 6a 48 53 64 41 72 46 46 41 44 42 36 30 75 36 53 73 6b 57 68 71
    39 48 48 53 69 6a 69 6c 57 39 68 4b 49 69 55 67 64 63 65 5a 41 50 68 4c 48
    31 4a 35 39 6f 4b 49 54 6e 67 71 4d 47 4d 69 6a 69 67 46 70 54 45 52 50 74
    5a 4c 42 2b 4d 4f 6a 49 71 4a 49 70 48 76 50 4a 72 72 66 52 67 34 6d 7a 77
    41 6d 5a 62 6b 2b 72 72 6f 70 79 59 68 61 34 72 42 4e 50 0a 2f 73 69 6d 2d
    63 61 6c 2d 62 75 63 6b 65 74 2f 74 65 6d 70 2f 66 6f 6f 2e 6d 70 34 3f 70
    61 72 74 4e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 31 26 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 49 64 3d 31</StringToSignBytes>
  <RequestId>073V6QJXMA0XAKWS</RequestId>
  <HostId>1pR1Pz4RSnRilgjUbb0AVDcMWiqCq05dMrAVU+0t4a0HF5ytfXmNiIecxH80urVoiKtxtHhxS2o=</HostId>
</Error>
```

So, we need to pass a `Content-Type` to signed url somehow. Neither [`generate_signed_url`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/generate_presigned_url.html) nor its `Params` (that must match params of [`upload_part`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_part.html)) accept `ContentType` option. This looks like a dead end... To double confirm, here's [what works in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684959/pre-signed-s3-url-signature-does-not-match) - `ContentType` is passed to the signer.

Well, for now I'm just monkeypatching botocore to allow passing `ContentType` parameter to `upload_part` (cloned [`botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json`](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/d95d441ef9b81ac4d0163fa97e736edf63a8b4b3/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json) and added this parameter to `UploadPartRequest` definition, patching this file in venv in Dockerfile), but it's certainly not what I want. However, this confirms that I *really* need to pass `ContentType`, and no other solution can allow setting this header. After uncommenting `ContentType` key in the sample above, everything is fine.

Just to compare, below are urls without and with content type - this arg is included in url directly. The latter URL works with frontend `fetch` flawlessly.

```
https://sim-cal-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/foo.mp4?partNumber=1&uploadId=1&AWSAccessKeyId=...&Signature=miwrnxtxoPdGnuAEqiP52ZMscBQ%3D&x-amz-security-token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEOT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDE%2B2gqVw4NTt1c2eOCKGAVTf4uDCD%2BGJ8P6lG2vBg8yQ2dqyU7%2F6aHg4hXMljyDFByT7hJ1%2FF%2FGPwBi84eAMDZqGzXpIySe8PhU80ak5C4vg7vcGOOSaB3cXk7TtQ2q0pWb8MB0AYb3LGAJ6sahySjHSdArFFADB60u6SskWhq9HHSijilW9hKIiUgdceZAPhLH1J59oKITngqMGMijigFpTERPtZLB%2BMOjIqJIpHvPJrrfRg4mzwAmZbk%2BrropyYha4rBNP&Expires=1684064749
https://sim-cal-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/foo.mp4?partNumber=1&uploadId=1&AWSAccessKeyId=...&Signature=1FeHhXi7QRtL0wCT7kJ%2BVEcBeso%3D&content-type=application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded&x-amz-security-token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEOT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDE%2B2gqVw4NTt1c2eOCKGAVTf4uDCD%2BGJ8P6lG2vBg8yQ2dqyU7%2F6aHg4hXMljyDFByT7hJ1%2FF%2FGPwBi84eAMDZqGzXpIySe8PhU80ak5C4vg7vcGOOSaB3cXk7TtQ2q0pWb8MB0AYb3LGAJ6sahySjHSdArFFADB60u6SskWhq9HHSijilW9hKIiUgdceZAPhLH1J59oKITngqMGMijigFpTERPtZLB%2BMOjIqJIpHvPJrrfRg4mzwAmZbk%2BrropyYha4rBNP&Expires=1684065651
```

Solutions suggesting to make a request without `Content-Type` are unacceptable, because this is a part of public API, and I do not want to make customers jump through hoops trying to send such request.

Comment: You need to set the content type on your call to `create_multipart_upload`, not set it for each individual part.

Comment: Tried that, it has zero effect, unfortunately. Moreover, it obviously does not work, since `generate_signed_url` is a local function (no requests), and it takes only `uploadId` for upload reference. As I have shown, even passing `uploadId = 1` (completely invalid rubbish) generates a signed url instead of failing. `ContentType` of created upload does not become part of signed url.

Comment: Upload `ContentType` is a content-type for actual file (it will be served with that content type after uploading). And I need to allow `Content-Type` header for incoming PUT request.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was confused by your comparison of using 'put_object' with your requirements.  If you can successfully monkeypatch the method to do the work, you might be best off opening a bug with boto3 or botocore, as this feels like a library omissions.

Comment: It's not really an omission: you cannot pass `ContentType` to `upload_part` directly, that API does not support it! If I try to invoke `upload_part` with `ContentType` passed, it'll most probably fail. However, in order to create a presigned URL I need that `botocore` allows passing `ContentType`. Seems like the real deficiency is using ClientMethod signature to determine allowed parameters for url signing - `ContentType` is needed for the latter and not for the former.

Comment: For context, I raised an issue as suggested [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3708).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the issue ([original](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3708), [following](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/548)) is not going to be resolved any soon (apparently), here's what we are doing now. The first snippet works for older `botocore` (1.28.1 certainly), and the second works for newer where this definition was gzipped. I'm not posting entire Dockerfile since it contains too many irrelevant details, but this extract should be sufficient (in fact it's a part of a longer `RUN` commands chain).

**Make sure to adjust venv location according to your setup.** You will need `jq` installed before (e.g. via `apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` for Debian/Ubuntu images).

```
# botocore 1.28.1
# Monkey-patch botocore to allow passing ContentType to presigned S3 upload URL
ARG BOTOCORE_PATCH_FILE=".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json"
RUN jq '.shapes.UploadPartRequest.members |= . + { \
        "ContentType": { \
          "shape": "ContentType", \
          "documentation": "<p>Upload Content-Type.</p>", \
          "location": "header", \
          "locationName": "Content-Type" \
        } \
    }' $BOTOCORE_PATCH_FILE > patch.json \
    && mv patch.json $BOTOCORE_PATCH_FILE
```

For command substitution, make sure to require `bash` shell.

```
# botocore 1.34.10
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-e", "-u", "-x", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
# ...
# Monkey-patch botocore to allow passing ContentType to presigned S3 upload URL
ARG BOTOCORE_PATCH_FILE=".venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json.gz"
RUN jq '.shapes.UploadPartRequest.members |= . + { \
        "ContentType": { \
          "shape": "ContentType", \
          "documentation": "<p>Upload Content-Type.</p>", \
          "location": "header", \
          "locationName": "Content-Type" \
        } \
    }' <(gunzip -c $BOTOCORE_PATCH_FILE) > patch.json \
    && gzip -c patch.json > $BOTOCORE_PATCH_FILE \
    && rm patch.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully Google picks this up adding a quick description to help

To make python pre-signed urls work in browser based javascript with boto3.

@STerliakov answer is correct that this is a bug in botocore and helped me track it down.
I don't expect AWS to fix this anytime soon.

But you can add a content-type without patching the service descriptors by wrapping _resolve_endpoint_ruleset function with a decorator.

This makes it a bit easier to maintain over time and across environments.

```py
s3_client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    region_name=os.environ.get("AWS_REGION"),
    aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
    aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
)


def resolve_endpoint_ruleset(method):
    def wrapper(operation_model, params, context, ignore_signing_region=False):
        (endpoint_url, additional_headers, properties) = method(
            operation_model, params, context, ignore_signing_region
        )  # Call the original method

        if "ContentType" not in params:
            additional_headers = {"Content-type": "binary/octet-stream"}

        return (endpoint_url, additional_headers, properties)

    return wrapper


s3_client._resolve_endpoint_ruleset = resolve_endpoint_ruleset(
    s3_client._resolve_endpoint_ruleset
)
```

In your create multipart upload method add a content type, it doesn't accomplish anything, but it lets you separate out the create from the generate methods

```py
response = s3_client.create_multipart_upload(
    Bucket=AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key=path,
    ContentType=content_type,  # Only purpose to separate create from generate
)

upload_id = response["UploadId"]
return jsonify({"uploadId": upload_id}), 200
```

Now you can create the presigned url without a content type and the decorator will inject your header.

```py
presigned_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    "upload_part",
    Params={
        "Bucket": AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        "Key": path,
        "UploadId": data["uploadId"],
        "PartNumber": data["partNumber"],
    },
    ExpiresIn=3600,
)
return jsonify({"url": presigned_url}), 200
```

This lets you keep the changes in your code and not have to modify the package contents.

Comment: I took the liberty to run all snippets through black - feel free to revert, but the snippets were unreadable in the previous format. Good idea anyway - thanks for sharing!

Comment: Much better ! I was fighting with the textbox